# Mysql: Fill column with consecutive numbers of days in a month

Tags: mysql

I have this table: "sales"

```
+-------------+---------+
| date        | total   |
+-------------+---------+
| 2018-12-04  | 269.10  |
| 2018-12-05  | 29.00   |
| 2018-12-06  | 107.10  |
| 2018-12-06  | 34.00   |
| 2018-12-08  | 69.50   |
| 2018-12-08  | 223.00  |
| 2018-12-08  | 68.00   |
| 2018-12-09  | 99.00   |
| 2018-12-10  | 59.50   |
| ...         | ...     |
+-------------+---------+
```

I'm trying this query

```
SELECT DAY(date) AS Days,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 12 THEN total ELSE NULL END) AS December  
FROM sales WHERE YEAR(date) = 2018 GROUP BY date
```

And I get

```
+-------+----------+
| Days  | December |
+-------+----------+
| 4     | 269.10   |
| 5     | 29.00    |
| 6     | 141.10   |
| 8     | 360.50   |
| 9     | 99.00    |
| 10    | 59.50    |
| ...   | ...      |
+-------+----------+
```

But I want consecutive days like this:

```
+-------+----------+
| Days  | December |
+-------+----------+
| 1     | NULL     |
| 2     | NULL     |
| 3     | NULL     |
| 4     | 269.10   |
| 5     | 29.00    |
| 6     | 141.10   |
| 7     | NULL     |
| 8     | 360.50   |
| 9     | 99.00    |
| 10    | 59.50    |
| ...   | ...      |
| 31    | 123.00   |
+-------+----------+
```

Can you help me plss..

PS: I have several months and years in "date" column from "sales" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursive CTE generates a list of dates corresponding to the month and year specified in the `doi` CTE, and then `LEFT JOIN`s that to the `sales` table to get the sales for that month. It will work for any  month/year, just change the values in the `doi` CTE, and the title of the SUM column (currently December) to suit.

```
WITH RECURSIVE doi AS (
  SELECT 12 AS month,
         2018 AS year
),
cte AS (
    SELECT DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, 1)) AS date
    FROM doi
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM cte
    WHERE date < LAST_DAY(date)
)
SELECT DAY(cte.date) AS Days, 
       ROUND(SUM(s.total),2) AS December
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.date = cte.date
GROUP BY cte.date
ORDER BY cte.date
```

Output is too long to show here but can be seen at this [demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tEXU6eMqTvT4kytzGqk7Yc/1)

**Update**

To expand this query to cover an entire year requires changing the approach slightly in terms of generating an entire year's worth of dates, and then using conditional aggregation to get the sums for each day of each month:

```
WITH RECURSIVE doi AS (
  SELECT 2018 AS year
),
cte AS (
    SELECT DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, 1, 1)) AS date
    FROM doi
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM cte
    CROSS JOIN doi
    WHERE date < DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', doi.year, 12, 31))
)
SELECT DAY(cte.date) AS Days, 
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 1 THEN s.total END),2) AS January,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 2 THEN s.total END),2) AS February,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 3 THEN s.total END),2) AS March,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 4 THEN s.total END),2) AS April,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 5 THEN s.total END),2) AS May,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 6 THEN s.total END),2) AS June,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 7 THEN s.total END),2) AS July,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 8 THEN s.total END),2) AS August,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 9 THEN s.total END),2) AS September,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 10 THEN s.total END),2) AS October,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 11 THEN s.total END),2) AS November,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.date) = 12 THEN s.total END),2) AS December
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.date = cte.date
GROUP BY DAY(cte.date)
ORDER BY DAY(cte.date)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tEXU6eMqTvT4kytzGqk7Yc/2)

Comment: @Rodrigo was this of any help?

Comment: Works nicely, but how to add november month?. Show me in the demo plss

Comment: @Rodrigo you want November as well as December?

Comment: Yes, both. 2018-12-08 ... 2018-11-05

Comment: Side by side (i.e `Days | December | November`) or in consecutive rows (i.e. `Day | Sales`)

Comment: Side by side ( Days | November | December ) because  I have 12 months

Comment: @Rodrigo something like this? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tEXU6eMqTvT4kytzGqk7Yc/2

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

generate your `months` using union and do `right join`

```
select t1.d as Days
    , sum(iif(month(date) = 12, total, null) as December
from sales
right join (select 1 as d
        union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6
        union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11
        .... ) as t1 on t1.d =  day(date)   
where year(date) = 2012
group by date
```

if you are using `mysql v8.0`, you can use recursive queries.

```
with recursive cte as(
    select 1 as d
    union all
    select d + 1 from cte where d < day(last_day('2019-12-01'))
)
select coalesce(day(s.date), t1.d) as Days
    , sum(iif(month(s.date) = 12, total, null) as December
from sales s
right join cte as t1 on t1.d =  day(s.date)
where year(date) = 2012
group by coalesce(day(s.date), t1.d)
```

Comment: I'm using v8.0 but not working. it says: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't1.d' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: It runs but fails in december of 2018, it start from 4 and doesn't have consecutive numbers. In december 4 - 2018 sales starts, not before

Comment: another way is to left join your sales table to cte

Comment: 2019 work perfectly but 2018 start for 4 not 1 why this is happening?. Can you help me? I will accept this answer as solved

Comment: try  change `coalesce(day(s.date), t1.d)` to `coalesce(t1.d, day(s.date))`